# Create a list from a list without nesting

Tags: r, list

Lets say I have a list: `x <- list(mtcars, iris, cars)`

Now lets say I want to add another dataset to the list. Adding one to the end is easy. `x[[4]] <- df`

But let's say I want to add an element to the beginning or let's say I want to combine two lists into one list. I cannot do something like this

```
list(df,x) # not equal to list(df, mtcars, iris, cars)
```

With `c` this would work, but the above would give me a list with a list nested as the second element.

Is there to create a list from a list without nesting?

Comment: @thelatemail That worked I'll accept it if you make it an answer

Comment: You might want to know about `merge.list` in package `taRifx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a `list` to add to the other `list`s, so:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10)
c(list(df), x)
#List of 4
#...
```

You can use `append` too, but you need to pass a `list` again:

```
append(list(df),x)
# equivalent to:
append(x, list(df), after=0)
```

...which means you can specify exactly where you want `df` added in the order of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use the append function. 
For example:

```
x <- list()

x <- append(x = x, c(mtcars, iris, cars))
```

Comment: Something like `x <- list(mtcars, iris, cars)` followed by `append(df, x)` doesn't give a list of 4 like I would expect

Comment: Yeah because you are appending a single list to df. You need to do append(x, c(mtcars, iris...))